# realsense pointcloud

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, camera-depth-points

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.
I am using a realsense camera. I have a question. Whether it is possible to filter the cloud of points obtained and depth image?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/377248/realsense-pointcloud/) by [Splinter1984](https://answers.ros.org/users/72957/splinter1984/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2021-04-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

> Whether it is possible to filter the cloud of points

Yes, it is possible to filter the cloud point, what you can do you just subscribe to the point cloud topic and you can process the point cloud according to your requirement. I found this [link](https://pcl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/passthrough.html) it may be helpful to you.

> filter for depth image

The realsense_camera driver is also providing filters for depth stream. They are disparity, spatial, temporal, hole_filling, and decimation. You can get details information in the below two links.

[Link 1](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/realsense-ros), [Link 2](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/master/doc/post-processing-filters.md)

You can comment if you have more doubt about this.

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2021-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2